# compute a roto-translation for 3D mesh

Tags: r, 3d, blender, meshlab

My EinScan SP 3D scanner is producing objects which are rotated & translated relative to its real-world orientation.

[image: rotated cylinder of soil sample]

The unit has already been calibrated and I do not plan to move it.

I need to compare many scans of the same object after subjecting it to a mechanical test.

I am interested in spatial measurements and morphometrics, but the objects need to be aligned with 'real-world' coordinate system to do so.

How can I re-orient the objects programmatically, i.e. without manually adjusting each 3D object ?

Comment: Are you really trying to do this in the [R programming language](https://www.r-project.org/)? Or is the [tag:r] tag a mistake? (Stack's tag-suggestion engine is good but imperfect, certainly.)

Comment: I am first trying to get the concept down by using MeshLab , and then I hope to automate the roto-translation matrix using the R packages Rvcg and Morpho.